# Finding the point closest to current point Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have essentially two select statements. This:

```
select 
    r."BeaconId",
    l."Coordinates",
from "Readings" r 
left join "Locations" l on
    r."BeaconId" = l."BeaconId"
where
    l."MapId" = 5
    and r."AbilityId" = 21
    and r."Timestamp" between NOW() - interval '1 DAY' and NOW()
```

and:

```
select
    mg."GatewayId",
    mg."Coordinates"
from "MapGateways" mg
where mg."MapId" = 5
```

The first one returns a set of coordinates for an associated beacon Id. This pings every 30s or so, and basically updates the location of the beacon in a new row every 30s.

The second one returns all the gateways on a given map. I want to integrate the second into the first. What I want is, to give the gateway Id which is closest to the each row of the first select statement.

For example:
say my first select statement has a row with beaconID of 5 at 0,0

say my second select statement produces a list of gateways like this:

| Id | Coords |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,1 |
| 2 | 4,4 |
| 3 | 4,5 |
| 4 | 5,5 |

Clearly, GatewayId of 1 is the closest to this beacon. So I want to find that ID, and put it in a column next to the output of the first select statement. That way I get the beaconID, coords, and the closest gateway at that point in time.

The result should be:

beaconID of 5 at 0,0 with the nearest gateway id of 1

How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: Please start with your Postgres (and PostGIS) version and exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement). And relevant indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through this https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html and http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html

what you are looking for is nearest gateway for each beacon

```
select 
    r."BeaconId",
    l."Coordinates",
    min(mg."Coordinates" <-> l."Coordinates")  
from "Readings" r 
left join "Locations" l on
    r."BeaconId" = l."BeaconId"
cross join "MapGateways" mg
where
    l."MapId" = 5
    and r."AbilityId" = 21
    and r."Timestamp" between NOW() - interval '1 DAY' and NOW()
    and mg."MapId" = 5
group by 
   r."BeaconId", l."Coordinates"
```

Don't forget to create indexes on "Coordinates" field of "Locations" and "MapGateways"